# Calling a method stored in object without also providing self in Python

Tags: python, class, object, callback

If you have a class that can store a function, in my case used as a callback, and I want to call this function without having to also give self as a parameter how do I do that? As en example:

```
class foo:
  def __init__(self, fun):
    self.fun = fun

  def call_fun(self):
    self.fun()
```

Now, I would have expected this forces fun to look like:

```
def fun(foreign_self):
  pass
```

since I expected object.fun() to be a shortcut for fun(object).

Edit: Updated the question to correctly reflect the situation.

Comment: *'this forces `fun` to look like...'* - what makes you think that?

Answer (score 3):

> Now, this forces fun to look like: `def fun(foreign_self)`

No, it does not. 
`fun` doesn't have to accept anything:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun

    def call_fun(self):
        print(self.fun)
        # <function fun at 0x02269588>
        self.fun()

def fun():
    print('in fun')

f = foo(fun)

f.fun()
# 'in fun'
f.call_fun()
# 'in fun'
print(f.call_fun)
# <bound method foo.call_fun of <__main__.foo object at 0x022239D0>>
```

Note that `fun` is a function while `call_fun` is an instance method. `call_fun` just happens to call the `fun` function by a reference that is kept within the instance.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am confused. I really thought the "object.fun" was just a convention for "fun(object)". How come this works?

Comment: @Robert In this case `f.fun()` simply runs the `fun` function as a function, not as a method. It has nothing to do with the `f` instance except for the object keeping a "shortcut" to the function. `print(f.fun) # <function fun at 0x00599588>` rather than `<bound method foo.fun of <__main__.foo object at 0x002C39D0>>` if it was a method.

Comment: @Robert Also see my updated answer, I added a small explanation and some example output.

Comment: @Robert cf https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod for more on how a function becomes (or, in this case, does not become) a method when invoked as an attribute of an object. To make a long story short: the function has to be an attribute of the _class_ to yield a method - if it's an attribute of the instance, it stays an ordinary function.